# Template function over a templated typedef

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have class that takes two template arguments:

```
template< typename T, size_t Len >
struct A {
    size_t GetLen() const {
        return Len;
    }

    T mArr[Len];
};

typedef A< int, 10 > IntArrOfTenLen;
typedef A< int, 5 > IntArrOfTenFive;
```

So far so good. Now I want to write a function that can do something with such typedef'd variables. Something like this:

```
void f(_arr)
{
    std::cout << _arr[_arr.GetLen() - 1];
}

void g()
{
    IntArrOfTenLen arr;
    IntArrOfTenFive arr2;
    f(arr);
    f(arr2);
}
```

Is it possible? What should be the signature of such function f()?

I have tried following:

```
template< typename A >
void f(A _arr) {
    std::cout << _arr[_arr.GetLen() - 1];
}
```

This fails because **Len** is not provided, but that providing Len will be kind of defeating the purpose of writing GetLen(), isn't it?

Comment: Have you tried to make it a template, and what was the problem you found?

Comment: `_arr[_arr.GetLen()]` will overflow the array.

Comment: @TartanLlama, it would not even compile, it should be `_arr.mArr[...]`.

Comment: True. `_arr.mArr[_arr.GetLen()]` will overflow the array :p

Comment: updated fixed @TartanLlama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `f` to take `A`s of arbitrary type and length, make it a template function:

```
template <typename T, size_t Len>
void f(const A<T,Len>& arr) {
    //...
}
```

You don't need to supply `T` and `Len` with this template; they'll be deduced from the argument:

```
f(arr)  //f<int, 10>
f(arr2) //f<int, 5>
```

Of course, instead of reinventing the wheel, you could just use `std::array` in C++11 rather than writing your own.

Comment: Array is hypothetical here. My usage is quite big so I simplified my question using array as an example.

Comment: @AnupamSrivastava Okay. Does this solve your problem or are there other aspects not covered?

Comment: No unfortunately, as the whole thing is there so as to avoid specifying Len. I have updated question with this info.

Comment: @AnupamSrivastava You don't need to specify `Len`, it will be deduced. You'll just call like `f(arr)`.

Comment: Thanks! You are right! Could you add this info in the answer?